# VB.net Excel set view to Page Layout

Tags: excel, vb.net, autocad

I´m trying to change the view in Excel document to Page Layout using vb.net.

```
 objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 objExcel.Visible = True
 objExcelWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
 objExcelWS = objExcelWB.ActiveSheet
```

I have done my programming (in AutoCAD and Excel) and everything works.

I would like to have my created Excel documents in Page Layout view.

I can't see any method for the Worksheet or Workbook to access the view settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`View`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.window.view?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Window_View) property of either the [ActiveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.activewindow?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel__Application_ActiveWindow) object, or for all [Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.window?view=excel-pia) objects in the [Windows collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.windows?view=excel-pia) for the target Workbook to [`xlPageLayoutView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlwindowview?view=excel-pia) (3).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Could this be the solution if I was using VBA ?
I am looking for a solution for VB.net.

Comment: @ÞorleifurDolliHjálmarsson Apologies - I have updated the documentation links - the method should remain the same however.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you. (forgot to reply, sorry).
    objExcel.ActiveWindow.View = 3